# Xamarin Forms Image doesn't get shown

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I want to use an IconView to change the color of an Image, so I use this project: https://github.com/andreinitescu/IconApp.

Now I added the Renderers in both IOS and Android and I added the IconView.cs class to the project. In my xaml I am trying to use the following code:

```
<controls:IconView Source="ledstrip" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Foreground="Red" />
```

But when I run my app, nothing shows up and I have no clue what I am doing wrong? If I create the following Image:

```
<Image Source="ledstrip" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" />
```

The image gets shown!

Here is my full XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Bluepixel.Tools"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Bluepixel.Pages.Devices">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding knownDeviceList}" SelectionMode="None" RowHeight="90" ItemTapped="device_Clicked" x:Name="MyListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteDevice, Source={x:Reference MyListView}}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                    Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>

                        <AbsoluteLayout HeightRequest="70" Margin="20,10,20,10">
                            <StackLayout Opacity="0.3" BackgroundColor="White"
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                            <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" 
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                                <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <controls:IconView Source="ledstrip" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" Foreground="Red" />


                                    </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </AbsoluteLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: pls show full xaml

Comment: I have added the full XAML above!

Comment: are u not missing the `assembly`

Comment: `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Bluepixel.Tools;assembly=Bluepixel.Tools"`

Comment: That gives me the error: `Assembly 'Bluepixel.Tools' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built`

Comment: The error disappears when I use this line: `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Bluepixel.Tools;assembly=Bluepixel"`, but that results in the same.... No image on the screen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library is not use to change the color of an Image, if you see the source code in the renderer in the `iOS` project, it changes the [tintColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview/1621059-tintcolor?language=objc) of UIImage in iOS:

```
var uiImage = new UIImage(Element.Source);
uiImage = uiImage.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
Control.TintColor = Element.Foreground.ToUIColor();
Control.Image = uiImage;
```

You can see the document and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950489/what-is-tint-in-xcode) to know how tint color works.

After some test, I found if you use a image which background is **transparent**, the image will show successfully with this plugin.

I uploaded a sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Icon-image) and there are several images you can test under resource folder. I think it's the same behavior in Android.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I got a question. Did you change anything in the code or not, because I am using an Image with a transparent background and that is not working!?

Comment: I can't test it on iOS, only on Android and that is not working right now

Comment: No, I did not change the code, you can have a try with my sample. I will update Android part later.

Comment: But I don't have an Mac or iPhone to test on for iOS, so I need the Android version!?

Comment: Please check the new link I updated in the answer for Android version.

Comment: And where is your IconView.cs class? Did you forgot it?

Comment: It's in the MainPage.cs.

Comment: I don't know why, but it is working now! Probably a copy/paste mistake!